# Drupal 7 How to use render element instead of variables in hook_theme()

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm having trouble understanding the 'render element' key purpose when implementing hook_theme().

```
function personal_news_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'teaser_list_by_user' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
    ),
  );
}
```

I did my research and the way I understand it, the `render element` key is use when creating a theme function to modify another theme function's output ONLY! And there's no way to use it as to implement a new theme function.
If I'm wrong, how can I use it instead of `variables`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example below, I created a new theme function using a *render element*.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function rojo_theme() {
  $items = array(
    'rojo_content' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Theme function.
 */
function theme_rojo_content($vars) {
  return '<pre>' . print_r($vars, TRUE) . '</pre>';
}

/**
 * Render function.
 */
function rojo_render() {
  $build = array(
    '#theme' => 'rojo_content',
    '#module' => 'rojo',
    'content' => 'Page content for the render function',
    'list' => array('one', 'two'),
    'tag' => 'div',
  );
  return render($build);
}
```

This will print the output of the `$vars` passed into the theme function. From here, you should be able to see what is going on. The `#theme` property will be called with `theme()` and passed the `$build` array during the `render()` process. Notice I added `#module` property and Drupal added the `#printed` / `#children` properties.

This is purely an example to demonstrate the creation of a new theme function using `render element` and argument passing. I hope this helps somebody out.

```
Array
(
  [element] => Array
    (
      [#theme] => rojo_content
      [#module] => rojo
      [content] => Page content for the render function
      [list] => Array
        (
          [0] => one
          [1] => two
        )
      [tag] => div
      [#printed] => 
      [#children] => 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your theme function returns an array - you can specify which key of the array to use for rendering.

> **render element**: The name of the renderable element or element tree to pass to the theme function. This name is used as the name of the variable that holds the renderable element or tree in preprocess and process functions.

(Source: [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7))