# Drupal add render element from module in theme template

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I've created a module that returns a bit of text, with the intent that this could be rendered in a theme template file. Seems like this should be straightforward, but I'm getting tripped up on something. So far I've been basing my attempts on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644323/drupal-7-how-to-use-render-element-instead-of-variables-in-hook-theme), and I've created the following functions in my module:

```
function daily_hours_theme() {
  $items =  array(
    'daily_hours_text_content' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
    )
  );
  return $items;
}

function theme_daily_hours_text_content($vars) {
  return daily_hours_get_text();
}

function daily_hours_text_content_render() {
  $build = array(
    '#theme' => 'daily_hours_text_content',
    '#module' => 'daily_hours',
    'content' => daily_hours_get_text(),
  );
  return render($build);
}

function daily_hours_get_text($day = null) {
  // Logic to get correct text content and store in $hours
  return $hours;
}
```

I've been trying to render the text with the following in my theme file:

`print drupal_render($daily_hours_text_content_render);` and
`print drupal_render($daily_hours_text_content);`

but not having any luck. The text *does* render if I call `print theme('daily_hours_text_content')` directly. It also renders if I provide the following array in my template file before calling `print drupal_render($render_array);` -

```
    $render_array = array(
      '#theme' => 'daily_hours_text_content'
    );
```

So it seems like the theme function is working, but not the render, or I'm not properly using the `drupal_render` function in my template file. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Your `theme_daily_hours_text_content` function should be returning the html, not printing it, like the `theme_rojo_content` function does in the post you linked to.
If you want to use a template file, it's probably better to use the `variables` array key instead of `render element` and also set the `template` array key. Take a look at the docs for [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

Comment: My `theme_daily_hours_text_content` is returning text, not printing it. I'm only calling `print` when trying to render in the template file. And I don't really want to use a template file for this - I want to make the render array available to a theme template file that's already in use.

Comment: ? to use an already registered theme function or file, you just need to call the [theme function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7) with the appropriate arguments, no need to register your own theme

Comment: Yes, it's working when I call the `theme` function directly, but not when I try to use `drupal_render`, which is advised in the theme function docs you linked to.